# Combine different Android Studio projects

Tags: android

I'm developing an app using android studio with my friend, but Im coding in my house, and he is coding in his house. We want to 'combine' both projects fragments (I will create some screens and code, he will create some screens and code too).

How do I combine both 'projects' in a single project?

Comment: It's very difficult to combine things after the fact. Ideally, you should use version control, both decide on the master version, both synchronize on that, and then manually merge the changes from the second version to the master version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use VCS Version Control system like [GitHub](https://github.com/)
 or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) they both free at least for small needs you can create a repository and then you both can push your code and pull it and those Version control systems will merge you code
if you are using Android Studio you can find VCS button click on it and select the system you are using so you can use this plug in to manage your operation and those are some useful links to get started with github
[link1](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide),[link3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D0fKg7e37bQE&ei=WjSTVdfeH8nWUa74hPAE&usg=AFQjCNFFOhQob0NRp9-LnNFUrKRMbQhSiw&sig2=fKklMmJdP9QctItmD5mL0g&bvm=bv.96952980,d.d24)
and for bitbucket
[link1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fconfluence.atlassian.com%2Fdisplay%2FBITBUCKET%2FBitbucket%2B101&ei=fjSTVfqLIsz9UPjthpAF&usg=AFQjCNEwQYM6Lto3LnCBetPgl0-Nmo9Afw&sig2=KmO6SuZSHc6en5Y3D0dcpg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.d24),[link2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.atlassian.com%2Fgit%2Ftutorials%2F&ei=fjSTVfqLIsz9UPjthpAF&usg=AFQjCNH2G-uXfwVT1-Ygoq90RgRgbWltpw&sig2=fxsGOJMy7kbQ7kBbstKOQg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.d24)