# Android studio importing two projects as one

Tags: android, import, module, project

I have made two projects in android studio. Say, **Project A** and **Project B.**

> When I run **Project A** on an emulator, it lists the available WiFi connections.
>   **Project B** lists the names of the devices connected to my WiFi.

I want the functionalities of both in a single project. So, I imported Project B as a 'module dependency' to Project A. But When I run project A, it performs the functions of Project B and not Project A.

-How do I list the available WiFi connections and list the names of the devices in a single project?

-Is there any other way of 'merging' projects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656023/androidstudio-module-dependencies-in-gradle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150499/combine-different-android-studio-projects